# Reactnative Password field toggle not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to toogle the secureTextEntry on my password textinput so the user can see what are they writing.

The funny thing is that I made it work when I use the export default class something extends component but I couldn't post the username and password.
This is my code.

```
const AuthForm = ({ errorMessage, onSubmit }) => {
    const [vCellphone, setvCellphone] = useState('');
    const [vPassword, setvPassword] = useState('');


    onPassPress = () => {
      this.setState({
        secureTextEntry: !this.state.secureTextEntry
      });
    }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/Logotipo-All.png')} />
        <Text style={styles.textIniciar}>Iniciar sesión</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textIniciar}> </Text>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
            placeholder="Teléfono"
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
            onChangeText={newvCellphone => setvCellphone(newvCellphone)}
            keyboardType={'numeric'}
            value={vCellphone}
            autoCorrect={false}
            />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
            placeholder="Contraseña"
            secureTextEntry={this.state.secureTextEntry}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
            onChangeText={newvPassword => setvPassword(newvPassword)}
            value={vPassword}
            autoCorrect={false}
            />
        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={this.onPassPress}>
            <Image style={styles.inputIcon} source={require('../assets/Visualización.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        {errorMessage ? (
                <Text style={styles.errorMessage}>{errorMessage}</Text>
            ) : null}
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]}  
         onPress={() => onSubmit({ vCellphone, vPassword })}>
        <Text style={styles.loginText}>INGRESAR</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
  );
};
```

This is the error I got:

> `undefined` is not an object (evaluating_this.state.secureTextEntry)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now your TextInput is trying to access `this.state.secureTextEntry` on render and will error out because

1) You don't have a `this.state` because you're using a React Hook

2) You don't have an initial state for `secureTextEntry`

You need to initialize the secureTextEntry value in your state using useState like this:

```
const [secureTextEntry, setSecureTextEntry] = useState(true);
```

and access it accordingly in your jsx like this:

```
onPassPress = () => {
    setSecureTextEntry(!secureTextEntry);
}

<TextInput 
    secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry} 
    ...rest of props omitted for brevity
/>
```

Comment: did that and i still have the same error, how should i put setSecureTextEntry?

Comment: Updated answer! Didn't realize at first you were trying to use this.state in a react hook

Comment: You're welcome, managing state differently between classes and hooks is an easy gotcha!